# grails image processing

Tags: java, javascript, image, grails, groovy

I have a form wherein the user will be able to provide an image either by:

- uploading it from their computer
- entering the URL of an image on the web

Once the image is provided, the user should be able to select an area of the image to be cropped using a JavaScript control. The cropped image will be resized to have a standard width. I may use an image hosting service (e.g. ImageShack) to store the image online instead of in the local filesystem. So to summarize, the functionality I'm looking for is:

- image area selection (for cropping)
- image resizing
- image hosting service integration

Is there a Grails plugin or Java library that can meet these needs?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that the selection process is fairly easy given a javascript plugin ( http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/).

I think the state of the art in the Grails world for resizing images would be the burning image plugin ( http://grails.org/plugin/burning-image ).

The image quality you get from it is not spectacular. You can also call imageMagick directly via groovy, but the setup and portability of this is not great.

Personally, I would go for a simpler library like ImgScalr - http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/

So the pieces are all there, but there isn't really a plugin that will do all of this for you in the Grails world.

You might also take a look at Gaelyk and the Google App Engine, as the image resizing support there is much nicer and more portable.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the image manipulation functionality you are seeking can be handled directly by the Java APIs (standard edition), e.g. in classes [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and [`AffineTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html).

Many [simple](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-scale-a-bufferedimage) [examples](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/) can be found on the web by searching for "java resize image", for example.

Comment: I think it's the bits not covered by `AffineTransform` and `BufferedImage` that Don is looking for. ie; the javascript crop selection tool, the serverside manipulation based on this crop and the handling of the image service api

Comment: Why do you think tools like ImageMagik are so popular if the Java APIs handle this adequately?

Comment: @Don fair enough...  My experience differs from yours

Comment: @Don: probably because the Java APIs are general and ImageMagick is task-based.  For example, with ImageMagick you can just call something like `convert foo.jpg -size 300x500 bar.jpg` instead of having to know what an affine transform is or how to build the transformation matrix and deal with the related Java objects.